Codeforces compiler shows a different output than Code::Blocks (problem CF16-D2-B)
my code outputs is exactly as the test cases only on codeBlockes and other online compiler, but in CF it is different, i think it is undefined behavior but i cannot spot it in the code.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,m,a,b,cnt;
    vector<int>arr;
    cin>>n>>m;

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        cin>>a>>b;
       arr.insert(arr.end(), a, b);

    }

  sort(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend());




    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cnt+=arr[i];

    }

    cout<<cnt;

    return 0;
}



Please [edit] your question to include the input you are giving, the output you should get (based on the input) and the output you are getting instead when using codeforces compiler

cnt is not initialized. Please enable all compiler warnings.

@3CxEZiVlQ: iterator insert( const_iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value );.  It inserts a copies of the value b.  Better variable names than a,b would make it more clear.

Your code contains undefined behavior so it is fundamentally broken and any result you get with any compiler is equally valid.

cnt is not initialized.
Turn on warnings for whatever compiler you are using.  Some compilers may need optimizations turned on as well, in order to warn about uninitialized variables.
For instance on godbolt:
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:27:12: warning: 'cnt' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   27 |         cnt+=arr[i];
<source>:9:17: note: 'cnt' was declared here
    9 |     int n,m,a,b,cnt;
      |   

(By the way, godbolt also has a format option if you right click.  See how much better your code looks with consistent indentation and formatting?)
